# Connection between The Eternal Cylinder, and War of the Worlds

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I wish to ask about the connection between The Eternal Cylinder Game, and the classic War of the Worlds. For the latter, it was originally a book, but then leading to the iconic TV show, there was also a radio show.

I feel there is a lot of connection especially in the narration and soundtrack, but also in the larger narrative themes. Though i'm not sure.

What type of thematic question would be a good fit for the site?

Alternatively, would this be a better fit for a more thematic/literary/narrative based SE, and from experience, would they mind that I was asking about a computer game?